# Apache NiFi - How to combine each flow file with a 'boilerplate' one?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have been battling to solve the following requirement in NiFi. Can anyone suggest anything?

In this example, let's say the .zip I start with is called source.zip and contains

- file1
- file2
- file3
- fileA

What I want to do is to generate a bunch of zips as follows;
file1.zip containing file1 and fileA
file2.zip containing file2 and fileA
file3.zip containing file3 and fileA

The reason for using NiFi is that the incoming zips are part of a dataflow.

I haven't found a combination of processors that allows me to do this. At the moment I'm doing a route on attribute to isolate fileA, putting that into a distributedmapcache, writing it to disk and then WAITing the other flowfiles until it appears. When it does I'm spawning a python script process to zip each flowfile with the fileA and return it. This kinda works but I am getting out of memory issues with large files despite increasing the java RAM, because I'm reading to memory in Python.

I'd love to get away from the Python and try and get it all done with Processors but haven't found a way to do it so far :(

Comment: the first idea - why not to do it in python starting with unzip and building multiple zips?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and respond Daggett.
That may be the way I need to end up going I think. The reason I'd opted for NiFi to start the process was;
The original files arrive in the folder from an upstream server, so I'd need to use some kind of watcher process
There's a bit of pre-processing needed after they arrive, which was quite easy in NiFi; the arrived files are tars and need untaring, decrypting, unzipping and each file base64 decoding.

That's the point at which each decoded file needs zipping along with the boilerplate json or xml file.

Comment: another idea: as the very first step use script to extract archive and assign attributes required for Mergecontent processor: `fragment.identifier=original_file_name+fileN_name,
fragment.index,
fragment.count=2`. For each fileN - set fragment.index=0, for fileA - fragment.index=1. Then execute all required preprocessing and as final step use Mergecontent with zip format - it should wait for each pair and zip them.

Comment: It looks as though I've managed to solve it based on that suggestion with a few tweaks, Daggett:

UnpackContent (to unpack the zip)
RouteOnAttribute (to find the fileA)
DuplicateFlowFile for FileA (with a value of ${fragment.count}-1
For each Duplicated FileA, UpdateAttribute to set fragment.count=2, fragment.index=0

For each FileN, UpdateAttribute (fragment.count=2, fragment.index=0)

Route success for both FileA and FileN to UpdateAttribute (to make filename=${segment.original.filename}_${filename}

To MergeContent set to Defrag, zip and number of bins=1

Thanks so much!